# How to create checkbox todo list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am having trouble trying to create a simple to-do list in LaTex.  Basically, what I want is a list with empty squares/boxes down the left side instead of bullets, numbers, letters, etc.

Here is what I have been playing around with:

```
%%To do list%%

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
    %\setenumerate[0]{label=(\square*)}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[checklist]{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\square{enumi}}

%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Box$}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\begin{document}
My todo list.\\
Immediate plan of action.\\

\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\renewcommand{\enumerate}{
  \oldenumerate
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item List item 1 goes here.  
        \item List item 2 goes here. 
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Sublist item 1 goes here. 
                \item Sublist item 2 goes here. 
            \end{enumerate}
        \item List item 3 goes here
        \item List item 4 goes here.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I have tried placing the new command after `\begin{enumerate}` in a few different ways, even tried to place it before and after `\item`, but nothing seems to work. I can get the list to enumerate with circles, stars, diamonds, etc. but for some reason, not the box/square.  What am I doing wrong?

I have been using LaTex for nearly a decade now and know there are more-often-then not numerous ways to achieve the same goal with LaTex, yet, I cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I would use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (and not intermix it with using the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\begin{document}
My ToDo list

\begin{itemize}
  \item Immediate plan of action.

  \begin{todolist}
    \item List item 1 goes here.
    \item List item 2 goes here.
    \begin{todolist}
      \item Sublist item 1 goes here.
      \item Sublist item 2 goes here.
    \end{todolist}
    \item List item 3 goes here
    \item List item 4 goes here.
  \end{todolist}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

We create a new type of list called `todolist`, which has two levels of nesting and is based on `itemize`. Each label within a `todolist` is set as `$\square$`, at both levels.

Comment: @samcarter; thank you cleaning up my first post. @Werner; thank you for the code, it is appreciated and what I was looking for.

Comment: If one does not want to use `$\square$` (for example in a pandoc template) one can also use the following:
`\newcommand{\checkbox}{\text{\fboxsep=-.15pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}\rule{1.5ex}{0pt}}}}` and then replace all `$\square$` with `\checkbox`.

Comment: that works fine! I use the `\tightlist`-command  in my other lists. It works here, too - just not at the end of the first-level-list before starting the 2nd-level-list. Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 122):

## Here is a variant of Werner's answer with checkmarks for recording progress.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}%
\hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}

\begin{document}
My ToDo list

\begin{itemize}
  \item Immediate plan of action.
  \begin{todolist}
  \item[\done] Frame the problem
  \item Write solution
  \item[\wontfix] profit
  \end{todolist}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the [suffix](https://ctan.org/pkg/suffix) package, it is possible to define, e.g., `\item*` instead of `\item[\done]`.

Answer (score 10):

I adjust the font size of the icon from packages `pifont` and `amssymb`, use `\raisebox` and `\hspace` to fit the icon position,  finally, it looks good, here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[$\square$]
no checked
\item[\rlap{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\hspace{0.4ex}\tiny \ding{52}}}$\square$]
failed
\item[\rlap{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\hspace{0.4ex}\scriptsize \ding{56}}}$\square$]
checked
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something super simple with no package dependencies.  This worked for me:

```
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item \lbrack\_\rbrack unchecked
    \item \lbrack x\rbrack checked
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: It would be nice, to not only show the `itemize` environment, but a minimal working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{docment}` (see the other answers). You should at least explain, which packages are needed for your suggestion. Without at least beginners would have problems in trying to use your code.

Comment: The point is NO packages are required at all. To my knowledge this itemize snippet can be cut and pasted into any LaTeX doc and it will work.

Comment: The standard LaTeX kernel environment `itemize` does not provide options to the environment itself. So you need either a class, that provides it or a package. However, if you think, your code does work with, e.g., `article` class without any package, show this, to show LaTeX beginners that it is such easy. But here I get: “`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`” if I only add `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` before your code and `\end{document}` after it.