# Side by side checkboxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, lists, positioning, forms

I'd like to put some checkboxes side by side, but I don't know how. The only thing I found so far was this for checkboxes, but that's just an explanation for how to do them.

[How to create checkbox todo list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247681/how-to-create-checkbox-todo-list)

I basically want the thing explained in that link, but instead the checkboxes should be displayed side by side. If that's not possible it all (which I doubt) it wouldn't matter that much, but I am copying something I wrote in Word into LaTeX and I would like for it to look the same.

Edit:
Basically, this is what I currently have:

[image]

... and this is what I actually want:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Frankly said, I do not understand your question. Please elaborate your question, at least with sketch from Word, which will show, what you like to have. And some effort, what you try so far will be also helpful.

Comment: Hello there. Basically, I wrote something in word which included checkboxes. It looks like this: http://imgur.com/Z5S8ECF I am now porting this whole thing into Latex and I would like for the checkboxes to like that, instead of this: http://imgur.com/XIRfnpE

Comment: `$\square$ something \quad $\square$ \quad something else`?

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun (pdf only):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\CheckBox[name=check1]{} Allgemein \hfil
\CheckBox[name=check2]{} Personalisiert \hfil
\CheckBox[name=check3]{} Keine Probleme

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\makebox[2cm][l]{$\square$ TextA}
\makebox[2cm][l]{$\square$ TextB}
\makebox[2cm][l]{$\square$ TextC}
```

Change `[2cm]`  to whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use the `wasysym` package, and with quick command to automate some proper spacing, here it goes.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand\insq[1]{%
    \Square\ #1\quad%
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Gab es irgendwelche technischen Probleme?}

\insq{Allgemein} \insq{Personalisiert} \insq{Keine Probleme}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

   \begin{itemize}

     \begin{todolist}

        \item List item 1 
        \item List item 2 
        \item List item 3 
        \item List item 4 
        \item List item 5  
        \item List item 6

          \end{todolist}

      \end{itemize}

   \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

A new environment can be made, specific to the checkboxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}

\newenvironment{Ckcol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
        \begin{todolist}}%
              {\end{todolist}%
                           \end{multicols}}
\begin{document}

   \begin{Ckcol}{3}

    \item  item 1 
    \item  item 2 
    \item  item 3 
    \item  item 4 
    \item  item 5  
    \item  item 6

   \end{Ckcol}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

[image]

And thanks to AlainRemillard for his help on eliminating an error through his comment. I had posted it as a separate question which produced a lot of great comments and an answer: [*Error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.'' using multicol in a \newenvironment, can it be fixed?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312428/90087)

Comment: you have two list enviroment in your Ckcol.  Remove the '\begin{itemize}' and '\end{itemize}' from your definition.