# Error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.'' using multicol in a \newenvironment, can it be fixed?

Tags: environments, itemize, multicol, enumitem

The below works, but produces an error message `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Does anybody know why it throws an error, and how to correct my code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}

\newenvironment{Ckcol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
        \begin{itemize}%
        \begin{todolist}}%
              {\end{todolist}%
                \end{itemize}%
                           \end{multicols}}
\begin{document}

   \begin{Ckcol}{3}

    \item  item 1 
    \item  item 2 
    \item  item 3 
    \item  item 4 
    \item  item 5  
    \item  item 6

   \end{Ckcol}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I started working on this trying to solve this question: [*Side by side checkboxes*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312394/90087)

Comment: `\begin{todolist}` is not an `\item` which is expected by `itemize`. Why do you need the outer `itemize` at all?

Comment: Bypass, but not really good: `\newenvironment{Ckcol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
    \begin{itemize}%
      \item[]\begin{todolist}
      }%
      {\end{todolist}%
    \end{itemize}%
  \end{multicols}
}`

Comment: `\newenvironment{Ckcol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
        \begin{itemize}[label=$\square$]%
}{%
                \end{itemize}%
                           \end{multicols}}`

Comment: Removing the `itemize` environment produces the same result without complaining… But you can obtain the same result with the `tasks` package, which has more possibilities (items stretching over several columns, for instance).

Comment: Thank you all for the great comments, and for the great alternatives. If anyone would care to summarize I will gladly pick it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `itemize` (and `enumerate` etc. as well) environment deliberately expects an `\item` command to work, this isn't provided by `todolist`.

It can be cured by giving an `\item[]` with empty label, but this might shift the whole list to the right margin, but in total, the outer `itemize` environment isn't necessary at all!

A better way, numbering from left to right is using `tasks`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}%

\newenvironment{Ckcol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{#1}%
    \begin{itemize}%
      \item[]\begin{todolist}
      }%
      {\end{todolist}%
    \end{itemize}%
  \end{multicols}
}
\begin{document}

   \begin{Ckcol}{3}
    \item  item 1 
    \item  item 2 
    \item  item 3 
    \item  item 4 
    \item  item 5  
    \item  item 6
   \end{Ckcol}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task Foo 1
\task Foo 2
\task Foo 3
\task Foo 4
\task Foo 5
\task Foo 6
\end{tasks}


\end{document}
```