# Multi-lined right aligned text after side by side checkboxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sidebyside

Below is a minimal working example of a form I am creating.

I have an enumerated list. Each item is a title, followed by a description, and then some choices. To the right of the choices is some text that I would like right aligned. There are many items like this.

I don't know how best to say in words what I would like visually, so the picture I attached below is meant to illustrate that. I originally attempted to do this using [side by side checkboxes in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312407/104214) where I used a 3 column list, but the text was always too long for the third item and would never be located all on the far left side.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, oneside, final]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem, amssymb}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item \textbf{Item title}\\
\noindent Some description text here. Below are the choices.

\noindent
$\square$ YES \qquad $\square$ NO \hfill {\small This is some filler text to make a point. I would like 

\hfill this part of the text to be right aligned without the awkward space above.\\}
$\square$ YES \qquad $\square$ NO \hfill {\small The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\} 
$\square$ YES \qquad $\square$ NO \hfill {\small The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\} 
$\square$ YES \qquad $\square$ NO \hfill {\small The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I would like is for the description to the right of the checkboxes to start after the checkboxes, have the ability to be multiple lines and always be right aligned without have that awkward space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, oneside, final, showframe]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, before =\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}]
  \item \textbf{Item title}

        Some description text here. Below are the choices. Some description text here. Below are the choices.

        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{$\square$ YES \qquad $\square$ NO}l >{\small\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
           & This is some filler text to make a point. I would like this part of the text to be right aligned without the awkward space above. \\
           & The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
           & The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \\
           & The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
        \end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]