# Checklist in beamer using enumitem package

Tags: beamer, lists, enumitem

I am working with beamer and wanna make a slide including a check list . What I wanna do is exactly like in this link: [How to create checkbox todo list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247681/how-to-create-checkbox-todo-list). but in beamer instead.

I know that enumitem and beamer are not compatible and I have changed my codes according to this: [Does enumitem conflict with beamer for lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/does-enumitem-conflict-with-beamer-for-lists)

However, the \only command seems not to work within the itemize environment when enumitem package is used.

Here is my example code, which is not working:

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\newlist{checklist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[checklist]{label=$\square$}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt} {\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}\hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{My check list} 
\begin{itemize}
    \only<1->{\item Item 1}
    \only<2->{\item Item 2}
    \begin{checklist}
    \only<3->{\item [\done]checklist 21}
    \only<4->{\item [\wontfix]checklist 22}
    \only<5->{\item [\wontfix]checklist 23}
    \end{checklist}
    \only<6->{\item Item 3}
    \begin{checklist}
    \only<7->{\item[\done]checklist 31}
    \only<8->{\item[\wontfix]checklist 32}
    \end{checklist}
    \only<9->{\item Item 4}
    \begin{checklist}
    \only<10->{\item[\done]checklist 41}
    \only<11->{\item [\wontfix]checklist 42}
    \end{checklist} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please see the attached file for imagination and note that the items will show up one by one [image]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks a ton!

Chung

Comment: Don't use enumitem in beamer. Beside this: You should show example code in the question, not attach (which doesn't work) nor link them.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. I have added the code. Which package should I use to get this done instead of enumitem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the classic `itemize` environment. Together with the symbols from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313337/36296 this gives:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}%
    \hspace{-2.5pt}}
\newcommand{\wontfix}{\rlap{$\square$}{\large\hspace{1pt}\xmark}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item bla

            \begin{itemize}[<+->]
                \item[\done] blub
                \item[\wontfix] bla
            \end{itemize}

            \item blub
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Samcarter. This is exactly what I did (please see my code I just added). The thing is...I want to use \only for each item in the checklist as you can see from my example and it is not working :(

Comment: @Chung Don't do that. If you need more control about the appearance, use `\item<2->`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but I have a more simple solution. You can use `itemize` with font awesome package `\usepackage{fontawesome}` without any new environment or new commands environment. The good point also you have thousands of icons you can add it without any new commands check the documentation from here [awsomefont](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome?lang=en)

Simple

```
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\faCheckSquareO] Maintainable.
        \item [\faCheckSquareO] Reusable.
        \item [\faCheckSquareO] Well-Performed.
        \item [\faCheckSquareO] Reliable.
        \item [\faCheckSquareO] Resilient.
        \item [\close`] Secure.
    \end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives using  `bbding`, `wasysym` or nothing:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bbding}
\let\oldSquare\Square % defined also in wasysym
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\boxtimes$] none  
\item[$\square$] none \bigskip
\item[\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\times$}] none
\item[\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\phantom{\times}$}] none \bigskip
\item[\CheckedBox] wasysym
\item[$\XBox$]  wasysym 
\item[\Square] \texttt{wasysym (\textbackslash Square)}  \bigskip
\item[\oldSquare]  \texttt{bbding (also \textbackslash Square)} 
\item[\rlap{\Checkmark}\oldSquare]  \texttt{bbding} 
\item[\rlap{\XSolidBrush}\oldSquare]  \texttt{bbding} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```