# Create toggle boxes in latex

Tags: formatting

Can you create toggle boxes, like you can in `notion` within latex? If you don't know what I'm talking about, look at the two images below:

[image]

Comment: If it can be done with PDF, it can be done using the eforms package.

Comment: Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247681/how-to-create-checkbox-todo-list. There's some options. I would suggest this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313337/264591.